# как поменять Source Application.ResourseDictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть окно `SettingsWindow`, из которого можно менять язык приложения.
Текстбоксы и все остальное биндится к словарю. Как из `SettingsWindow` можно поменять `Source` `Application.ResourseDictionary`?

пробовал и так(`SettingsWindow.xaml.cs`)

```
    public event EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectionChanged;
    private void Ukrainian_OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseSelectionChanged("ua");
    }

    private void Russian_OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseSelectionChanged("ru");
    }

    private void English_OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseSelectionChanged("en");
    }

    protected void RaiseSelectionChanged(string SelectedItemName)
    {
        if(SelectionChanged!=null)
            SelectionChanged(this,new SelectionChangedEventArgs(){_SelectedItemName =SelectedItemName});
    }
```

С последующей обработкой события в `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
void win_SelectionChanged(object sender, WpfApplication1.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string tag = e._SelectedItemName;
        switch (tag)
        {
            case "ua":
                ResourceDictionary UaDict = new ResourceDictionary();
                Uri UaUri = new Uri(@"Localization\Ukrainian.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                UaDict.Source = UaUri;
                this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(UaDict);
                break;
            case "ru":
                ResourceDictionary RuDict = new ResourceDictionary();
                Uri RuUri = new Uri(@"Localization\Ukrainian.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                RuDict.Source = RuUri;
               this. Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(RuDict);
                break;
            case "en":
                ResourceDictionary EnDict = new ResourceDictionary();
                Uri EnUri = new Uri(@"Localization\Ukrainian.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                Endict.Source = EnUri;
               this. Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(EnDict);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

,но шиш там.

Comment: Вы пишете, что хотите поменять `Application.ResourseDictionary`, а реально пишете в `this. Resources.MergedDictionaries` (у вас, судя по всему, `this` — это MainWindow).

Comment: @VladD,код обработки события взят из обратботчика нажатия кнопки,которая раньше отвечала за это,но в MainWindow.мне нужен тот же функционал,только в отдельном окне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы добавляете `ResourceDictionary`, но не убираете при этом старый, так что он продолжает действовать.

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
static ResourceDictionary CurrentLocalizationDictionary;

void SetLanguage(string languageName)
{
    var rootResources = window.ResourceDictionary;
    // или this.ResourceDictionary
    // или Application.Current.Resources, если вы реально хотите
    //   поменять ресурсы для всего приложения, а не только главного окна
    var path = string.Format(@"Localization\{0}.xaml", languageName);
    var newDict = new ResourceDictionary()
    {
        Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    };
    if (CurrentLocalizationDictionary != null)
        rootResources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(CurrentLocalizationDictionary);
    CurrentLocalizationDictionary = newDict;
    rootResources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newDict);
}
```

Убедитесь, что все ссылки на строки даются через `DynamicResource`.